# Ubuntu 19.04 Revelation password manager

Tags: password, 19.04, keepass

Is there any possibility to open or import data from revelation file? I have many passwords in my file and I can't open it, because revelation is missing in Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open it you can temporarily install revelation by adding the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Install revelation

```
sudo apt-get install revelation
```

Open your file, export the data and import it to whatever you like. Afterwards, purge revelation again and do

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Alternatively, keep using revelation once installed.

Comment: This is not a proper format for sources.list, it shall be something after that, maybe `eoan` or `eoan partner`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and quite a trouble is installing revelation on the Ubuntu 19.04.
To save the data, I've installed CentOS 6.10 on the virtual machine, after adding epel-repo, update and upgrade, I could install revelation from rpm package [link](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/repoforge-i386/revelation-0.4.14-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm.html)  (download of the package is on the same page - [download](http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/dag/redhat/el6/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/revelation-0.4.14-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm))
After that install revelation with:

```
yum install revelation-0.4.14-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm
```

Then you can copy/download your revelation backup and export it to xml, csv or other password manager format like Gorilla - I switched to *Password Gorilla.*

Answer (score 0):

To anyone stuck without Revelation after migrating from 18.04 to 20.04, I have successfully made it run by locating the .deb package on 18.04 source lists:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/revelation/download

Downloaded the package, installed it (by double clicking on it), it still works on Ubuntu 20.04, even though it signals a missing library on startup.

Then I was able to migrate to another password manager.